# When calling a Laravel relation it is automatically appended. How does this work?

Tags: laravel

When calling:

```
$user->company
```

and then returning a JSON representation of `$user`, it appends the company relation to the response even if I don't want it to.

Does someone know the reason why this happens?

Comment: Do you return $user->company or just $user ?

Comment: @Cornest just $user and i call $user->company before returning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that `$user` is an instance of a `User` Eloquent model, and it has a defined relation of `company` which returns an instance of a `Company` Eloquent model.

Given the following code, you would return a JSON object which contained an output of properties on the `User` model, likely those defined by a `visible` property on the model (or all those except any defined by a `hidden` property on the model).

```
$user = User::findOrFail(1);
return $user->toJson();
```

In this example, the `company` relation wouldn't form part of the returned data (unless you were using the `with` property on the model to ensure it's always returned).

However, with the following code you would return a JSON object which contained an output of all properties on the `User` model, as well as a JSON representation of its linked `company` relation (assuming your `visible` or `hidden` property on the `User` model allowed this:

```
$user = User::findOrFail(1);
$user->company;
return $user->toJson();
```

The reason for the difference is that when calling the `toJson` method, Laravel uses a method called `getArrayableRelations` to determine which relations are available to be returned. Any relation that has already been loaded by the model instance will be included in this output.

When you call `$user->company` you are loading the `company` relation locally on the model instance, and it will then be included in any serialisation methods like `toArray` or `toJson`.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. But i have one more question. if i want to check if($user-company !=null) it will appends too. Can i somehow check that without appending to result?

Comment: Can i somehow check relation without appending?

Comment: You can't, any interaction with the relation will load it locally. However, you can `unset` it after loading it. That said, it would be better to instead improve how you return your JSON so it doesn't include unexpected relations. Eloquent API Resources are an excellent way of handling this: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-resources

Comment: Thanks for response. Can you write me code example of "unset"?

Comment: `unset($user->company)`

Comment: @Test you can use `$user->company()->exists()` to check without appending.

Comment: Be aware that using `exists` will make a separate database request even if the relation has been eager-loaded, so avoid doing this inside a loop.